# Detect Winks in front facing camera using CIFaceFeature

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have an app which uses AVFoundation and tracks the face, eyes, and mouth position. I use the CIFaceFeature to detect these and mark them on the screen.

Is there a simple way to detect a wink using the framework?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7, Yes, now you can do it with CoreImage.

Here is the API diff in iOS 7 Beta 2:

```
CoreImage

CIDetector.h
Added CIDetectorEyeBlink
Added CIDetectorSmile
```

Before iOS 7:

No, there is no way with iOS frameworks (AVFoundation or CoreImage) for now.

You can check out with OpenCV... but it's more of a researchy topic, not guarantee to work well in different situations:

First, you need to build a eye close/open classifier, afaik, there is no build-in eye wink classifier in OpenCV, so you need to collect enough "close" and "open" samples, and train a binary classifier. (I would suggest using Principle Component Analysis + Support Vector Machine. Both are available in OpenCV)

Then in iOS, use CoreImage to detect the locations of both eyes. And cut a square patch image around the eye center. The size of the patch should be normalized in terms of the detected face bounds rectangle.

And then you need to convert UIImage/CIImage to OpenCV IplImage or CvMat format, and feed them into your OpenCV classifier to determine the eyes are open or close.

Finally, determine if there is a wink based on the sequence of eye open and close.

(You also need to check if the processing frame rate is able to pick a wink action: say the wink happens within 0.5 frame... then you'll never detect it...)

It's a hard problem... otherwise Apple would have already included them in the framework.

Comment: The APIs are defined in the headers, but do they function in the current beta?